# Add button to each datagrid row

Tags: wpf

In the WPF datagrid, I want to show a button in the each first cell in the each row. It will show that row id (contactId) in the popup. so far I have this code.

The popup is not shown up. and how to get ContactId in that row ?

Thanks

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="False"  Height="186" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="EditBtn" >Edit</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Click, ElementName=EditBtn}" Margin="0,0,-101,0">
            <Border Background="LightYellow">
                <TextBlock> I'M the popup</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Button's Tag Property to the ContactID

```
<Button Name="EditBtn" Tag={Binding ...} >Edit</Button>
```